# Will all the worker threads get generated at once?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Is anyone out there who can explain me the flow of this code? 
I wonder how main thread generates worker threads, what I know is:

As soon as main thread calls .start method it creates a new thread. 
But I have a confusion how the behavior changes when it comes to looping multiple threads in main.

```
static void Main()
{
Thread[] tr = new Thread[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    tr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(count));
    tr[i].Start();

}

static private void count()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        lock (theLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Count {0} Thread{1}",
            counter++, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());

        }
    }
```

Is there a good way to debug and track your multithreaded program.  after google it out I found tracking thread window in debug mood,  but I couldn't find it useful even after given custom names to threads. 
I just can't understand the flow, how threads being launched, how they work all together etc as breakpoints seem no effect in multi-threaded application. (At least in my case.)

Comment: The thread will start executing "at some point very shortly after Start is called". However, since *very little* work is done inside each thread, it is unlikely that all the threads will be running at once (ie. the first threads may complete before the later threads are even created). Use `Thread.Sleep` inside the loop with a random value to see thread interleaving better.

Comment: It depends. You cannot know that for sure. Why would you need to know if all threads start "at once" or not.

Comment: I just want to know how they work so I can implement my logic, which I have been trying since last days.

Comment: @Eqra The point everyone is trying to make is when you are writing multi-threaded code you MUST write your logic so that your code *does not care* about the order the threads are started. Also `Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()` is the same thing as doing `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`, but the 2nd version makes it more obvious what information you are trying to get.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, sir I want this output 
1 printed by Thread :  4551  [ThreadID]
2 printed by Thread :  4552
3 printed by Thread :  4553
4 printed by Thread :  4554
5 printed by Thread :  4555
6 printed by Thread :  4556
7 printed by Thread :  4557
8 printed by Thread :  4558
9 printed by Thread :  4559
10 printed by Thread : 4560
11 printed by Thread : 4551  [ Same Thread Id Appears again as in 1]
12 printed by Thread : 4552
 That's why I want to track the threads and the point when they get generated to get the desired order. :( sorry If I am asking too much.

Comment: _"As soon as main thread calls .start method it creates a new thread"_ -- the `Thread` object is created as soon as you call `new Thread...`. The thread is put into a runnable state as soon as you call `Start()`. When the thread executes is up to the Windows thread scheduler, and it doesn't offer any guarantees of order. _"I want this output..."_ -- what's the point of that? If you want the work done in some specific order, put it all in a single thread. Your question isn't making much sense. At best, it's too broad, and at worst it's not clear at all what you really want the code to do.

Comment: Thanks to considering, I do try it at my end and then post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want this output 1 printed by Thread : 4551 [ThreadID] 2 printed by
>   Thread : 4552 3 printed by Thread : 4553 4 printed by Thread : 4554 5
>   printed by Thread : 4555 6 printed by Thread : 4556 7 printed by
>   Thread : 4557 8 printed by Thread : 4558 9 printed by Thread : 4559 10
>   printed by Thread : 4560 11 printed by Thread : 4551 [ Same Thread Id
>   Appears again as in 1] 12 printed by Thread : 4552

I'll try to describe what your code is doing as it interacts with the threading subsystem.  The details I'm giving are from what I remember from my OS design university classes, so the actual implementation in the host operating system and/or the CLR internals may vary a bit from what I describe.

```
static void Main()
{
Thread[] tr = new Thread[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    tr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(count));

    // The following line puts the thread in a "runnable" thread list that is
    // managed by the OS scheduler. The scheduler will allow threads to run by 
    // considering many factors, such as how many processes are running on 
    // the system, how much time a runnable thread has been waiting, the process
    // priority, the thread's priority, etc.  This means you have little control 
    // on the order of execution, The only certain fact is that your thread will
    // run, at some point in the near future.
    tr[i].Start();  

    // At this point you are exiting your main function, so the program should
    // end, however, since you didn't flag your threads as BackgroundThreads,
    // the program will keep running until every thread finishes.
}


static private void count()
{
   // The following loop is very short, and it is probable that the thread
   // might finish before the scheduler allows another thread to run
   // Like user2864740 suggested, increasing the amount of iterations will 
   // increase the chance that you experience interleaved execution between
   // multiple threads

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // Acquire a mutually-exclusive lock on theLock. Assuming that
        // theLock has been declared static, then only a single thread will be
        // allowed to execute the code guarded by the lock.    
        // Any running thread that tries to acquire the lock that is
        // being held by a different thread will BLOCK. In this case, the 
        // blocking operation will do the following:
        //    1. Register the thread that is about to be blocked in the
        //       lock's wait list (this is managed by a specialized class
        //       known as the Monitor)
        //    2. Remove the thread that is about to be blocked from the scheduler's
        //       runnable list. This way the scheduler won't try to yield
        //       the CPU to a thread that is waiting for a lock to be
        //       released.  This saves CPU cycles.
        //    3. Yield execution (allow other threads to run)
        lock (theLock)
        {
            // Only a single thread can run the following code
            Console.WriteLine("Count {0} Thread{1}",
            counter++, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());

        }
        // At this point the lock is released.  The Monitor class will inspect
        // the released lock's wait list. If any threads were waiting for the
        // lock, one of them will be selected and returned to the scheduler's
        // runnable list, where eventually it will be given the chance to run
        // and contend for the lock. Again, many factors may be evaluated 
        // when selecting which blocked thread to return to the runnable  
        // list, so we can't make any guarantees on the order the threads
        // are unblocked
    }
}
```

Hopefully things are clearer.  **The important thing here is to acknowledge that you have little control of how individual threads are scheduled for execution, making it impossible (without a fair amount of synchronization code) to replicate the output you are expecting.** At most, you can change a thread's  priority to hint the scheduler that a certain thread must be favored over other threads. However, this needs to be done very carefully, as it may lead to a nasty problem known as priority inversion.  Unless you know exactly what you are doing, it is usually better not to change a thread's priority.

Comment: Thanks to consider and take out time to make it easy-to-understand for me *_*

Comment: You're welcome, I see that you managed to obtain the interleaved sequence you were expecting, feel free to mark your own answer as the correct one.  =)

Comment: I am unable to do it now, Thanks for the next time *_*

Answer (score 0):

After a continuous try, I got to complete the requirements of my task. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
public class EntryPoint
{
    static private int counter = 0;
    static private object theLock = new Object();
    static object obj = new object();
    static private void count()
    {
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                lock (theLock)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Count {0} Thread{1}",
                    counter++, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());
                     if (counter>=10) 
                    Monitor.Pulse(theLock);
                    Monitor.Wait(theLock);  }  }}
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Thread[] tr = new Thread[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tr[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(count));
            tr[i].Start();
        }

    }
}
```

Monitor maintains a ready queue in a sequential order hence I achieved what I wanted:

[image: Here is the output]

Cheers!